# Visual Studio restarts while trying to install package

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, nuget-package

Does anyone know why my visual studio 2015 restart when I try to install nuget packages? It happens only on certain projects.

Comment: are you using visual studio dark theme by any chance?

Comment: Did you find the reason for this? Am having a similar issue here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36430840/nuget-package-manager-crashes-when-clicking-manage-nuget-packages-for-solution