# Nuget Package Manager crashes when clicking "Manage nuget packages for solution" Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget-package

So my Visual studio is crashing when clicking the "Manage nuget packages for solution" button. If I choose to debug I get this message

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: The URI prefix is not recognized.

It is only for this one project this happens but I have tried to reinstall Nuget Package manager but that doesn't work. Any help would be strongly appreciated.

I recently installed the latest update, "Update 2".

EDIT 1:
I can't get my head around this. In the Package manager for one of the projects I have located two rows that if I comment out, makes the Nuget Package Manager work without crashing. Well, until I search for one of the packages that is, then it crashes again. So I tried to open another solution that didn't have these packages, it worked fine until I also in this other project searched for one the below commented packages, then it crashed also there.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <!--packages omited for clarity -->
  <package id="EPiServer.CMS.UI.Core" version="9.4.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <!--<package id="EPiServer.Forms" version="1.1.4.9000" targetFramework="net451" />-->
  <package id="EPiServer.Framework" version="9.7.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <!--<package id="EPiServer.GoogleAnalytics" version="1.9.3.9000" targetFramework="net451" />-->
  <package id="EPiServer.Logging.Log4Net" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="EPiServer.Packaging" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="EPiServer.Packaging.UI" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <!--packages omited for clarity -->
</packages>
```

I don't know if it is my installation that is faulty or if is it something else.

EDIT 2:
I tried doing a search and look in fiddler to se what the result looks like, if it is corrupt or anything. The result I got was this one single package and if I go to that url (http://nuget.episerver.com/feed/packages.svc/Packages(Id='EPiServer.GoogleAnalytics',Version='1.9.3.9000')), everything looks fine. I guess it must be something with my Visual Studio installation even though I have made a repair on Visual Studio as well as an reinstall of Nuget Package Manager extension.

EDIT 3:
My colleague, who has not installed "Update 2" does not have this problem so it might be this update.

Comment: is your disk full?

Comment: no, far from full.